# Is Physical Location change in Storage Device affects Index of Oid reference

Tags: networking, snmp

I have IBM networking device (.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "AVFC400P.AMERUS.CORP.TLD")

In SNMP walk file It has multiple storage devices

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.1 = STRING: "System ASP"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.2 = STRING: "RAM "
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.3 = STRING: "RAM "
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.4 = STRING: "RAM "
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.5 = STRING: "RAM "
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.6 = STRING: "RAM "
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.7 = STRING: "RAM "
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.8 = STRING: "RAM "
```

As per reference https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.1
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.1 defines the identifier.

And As the descriptions are the same. We needed to know if We Add a change in the physical location of one RAM from one Location to Another. Does that also changes the index reference or not? As the description of Oids are same .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.2

Comment: The `hrStorageIndex` ought to be tied to the slot that the RAM plugs into. `hrStorageTable` is meant to let you see what is plugged into each slot

Comment: either the index should not changa (or it is a bug), or the index is changed in both tables so it still functions (or it is a bug).

Comment: The standard RFC documents do not have strict rules on whether index values can change, as long as they are unique when you query the table. It is up to the vendor (IBM) in your case to define the exact behavior, so you will have to contact the vendor for explanation.